# Grab cloth simulation like in Marvelous Designer

Tags: cloth-simulation

Is it possible to grab a cloth sim like in Marvelous Designer? If it's not possible is there an addon or a workaround?

Comment: https://twitter.com/JoseConseco3/status/1152681565404745728 or https://youtu.be/jNXBYI-WPU4?t=165 had this feature, but I'm not sure if any of this is for 3.x version ...

Comment: In *Sculpt* mode there is a *Cloth* brush and it has a grab mode (options) -- or you can use the *Pin* group with an *Empty* object as shown in the video. This requires no addon.

Comment: @Blunder Ha ... I thought it is more for wrinkles, but it really grabs in cloth style entire object ... only collision with other objects works weird for me, but probably my wrong setup. Thanks anyway for reminder :)